# Repeater Validation after Click on "Save" or "Submit"

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio

I have a link button and if I click on that button a pop-up will be displayed. In that pop-up i have some fields to enter like text box and drop down lists. I also have `Save` and `Cancel` buttons in that repeater so that I can validate those text fields.

When I click on "Save" or "Submit", the repeater is not validating. It should validate if repeater is not used, because, I have some required fields in that repeater.

Why is validation not happening?

```
<asp:Panel runat="server" ID="divAddNew" class="align-left">
                <asp:CustomValidator ID="cvRepeater" runat="server" CssClass="error" Text="Atleast one Club/Chapter should be enterd" Display="Dynamic" ValidationGroup="addlocation" ClientValidationFunction="ValidateRepeater"></asp:CustomValidator>
                <div class="clear"></div>
                <asp:LinkButton ID="lbAdd" CssClass="btn btn-primary" ToolTip="Add New Club/Chapter involved" runat="server" Text="" CausesValidation="false" OnClientClick="ValidateRepeater()">Add New Club/Chapter involved</asp:LinkButton>
            </asp:Panel>

            <div id="pnlClub" runat="server" class="biglist">
                <asp:Label ID="lblLocId" runat="server" CssClass="hidden" />
                <div class="align-center" style="background-color: #5b98ba; color: white; height: 25px; padding-top: 10px">
                    <asp:Label ID="lblClubTitle" CssClass="bold" runat="server" Text="lblLocationTitle"></asp:Label>
                </div>
                <div class="clear"></div>
                <div class="seperator-1"></div>
                <div class="prefix-1">
                    <div class="grid-6">
                        <label for="<%=ddlAppType.ClientID%>">BOAC Selection Type <span class="required">*</span></label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="grid-9">
                        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlAppType" runat="server" Width="300px"></asp:DropDownList>
                    </div>
                    <div class="clear"></div>
                    <div class="seperator-1"></div>
                    <div runat="server" id="divNames">
                        <div class="grid-6">&nbsp;</div>
                        <div class="grid-9">
                            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator3" Display="Dynamic" ControlToValidate="txtClubName" runat="server" Text=" Club/Chapter name required" ValidationGroup="addlocation" CssClass="error"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                            <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator6" Display="Dynamic" ControlToValidate="txtClubName" runat="server" Text="Enter a valid Club/Chapter name" ValidationGroup="addlocation" CssClass="error" ValidationExpression="^[\w ~!@#$&\*\(\)\+\-<>;:,.'/=`]*$"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
                        </div>
                        <div class="clear"></div>
                        <div class="grid-6">
                            <label for="<%=txtClubName.ClientID%>">Club/Chapter Name<span class="required">*</span></label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="grid-9">
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtClubName" runat="server" Width="300px" MaxLength="100"></asp:TextBox>
                        </div>
                        <div class="clear"></div>
                        <div class="grid-6">&nbsp;</div>
                        <div class="grid-9">
                            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvContactName" Display="Dynamic" ControlToValidate="txtContactName" runat="server" Text=" Contact Name required" ValidationGroup="addlocation" CssClass="error"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                            <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator1" Display="Dynamic" ControlToValidate="txtContactName" runat="server" Text="Enter a valid contact name" ValidationGroup="addlocation" CssClass="error" ValidationExpression="^[\w ~!@#$&\*\(\)\+\-<>;:,.'/=`]*$"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
                        </div>
                        <div class="clear"></div>
                        <div class="grid-6">
                            <label for="<%=txtContactName.ClientID%>">Contact Name <span class="required">*</span></label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="grid-9">
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtContactName" runat="server" Width="300px" MaxLength="100"></asp:TextBox>
                        </div>

                        <div class="clear"></div>

                        <div class="grid-6">&nbsp;</div>
                        <div class="grid-9">
                            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvAddress" Display="Dynamic" ControlToValidate="txtAddress" runat="server" Text="Address is required" CssClass="error" ValidationGroup="addlocation"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                            <%--<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegexAddress" Display="Dynamic" ControlToValidate="txtAddress" runat="server" Text="Enter a valid Address" CssClass="error" ValidationGroup="addlocation" ValidationExpression="(?:\s*[a-zA-Z0-9]{2,}\s*)*"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>--%>
                        </div>
                        <div class="clear"></div>
                        <div class="grid-6">
                            <label for="<%=txtAddress.ClientID%>">Mailing Address<span class="required">*</span></label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="grid-9">
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtAddress" runat="server" Width="300px" MaxLength="40"></asp:TextBox>
                        </div>

                        <div class="clear"></div>

                        <div class="grid-6">&nbsp;</div>
                        <div class="grid-9">
                            <%--<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegexLastName" Display="Dynamic" ControlToValidate="txtMailAdd2" runat="server" Text="Enter a valid Mailing Address" CssClass="error" ValidationGroup="addlocation" ValidationExpression="(?:\s*[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,}\s*)*"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>--%>
                        </div>
                        <div class="clear"></div>
                        <div class="grid-6">
                            <label for="<%=txtMailAdd2.ClientID%>">Mailing Address 2</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="grid-9">
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtMailAdd2" runat="server" Width="300px" MaxLength="40"></asp:TextBox>
                        </div>

                        <div class="clear"></div>

                        <div class="grid-6">&nbsp;</div>
                        <div class="grid-9">
                            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvCityName" Display="Dynamic" ControlToValidate="txtCityName" runat="server" Text="City name is required" CssClass="error" ValidationGroup="addlocation"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                            <%--<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegexCityName" Display="Dynamic" ControlToValidate="txtCityName" runat="server" Text="Enter a valid City name" CssClass="error" ValidationGroup="addlocation" ValidationExpression="(?:\s*[a-zA-Z0-9]{2,}\s*)*"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>--%>
                        </div>
                        <div class="clear"></div>
                        <div class="grid-6">
                            <label for="<%=txtCityName.ClientID%>">City<span class="required">*</span></label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="grid-9">
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtCityName" runat="server" Width="300px" MaxLength="40"></asp:TextBox>
                        </div>
                        <div class="clear"></div>
                        <div class="grid-6">&nbsp;</div>
                        <div class="grid-9">
                            <asp:CustomValidator runat="server" ID="cvState"
                                CssClass="error"
                                Display="Dynamic"
                                ClientValidationFunction="ValidateState"
                                Text="Select State" ValidationGroup="addlocation" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="clear"></div>
                        <div class="grid-6">
                            <label for="<%=ddlStateName.ClientID%>">State<span class="required">*</span></label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="grid-9">
                            <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlStateName" runat="server" Width="300px" onchange="stateClick();"></asp:DropDownList>
                        </div>
                        <div class="clear "></div>
                        <div class="grid-6">&nbsp;</div>
                        <div class="grid-9">
                            <asp:CustomValidator runat="server" ID="CustomValidator1"
                                CssClass="error"
                                Display="Dynamic"
                                ClientValidationFunction="ValidateCounty"
                                Text="Select County" ValidationGroup="addlocation" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="clear"></div>
                        <div class="grid-6">
                            <label for="<%=ddlCountyName.ClientID%>">County<span class="required">*</span></label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="grid-9">
                            <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlCountyName" runat="server" Width="300px"></asp:DropDownList>
                        </div>

                        <div class="clear"></div>

                        <div class="grid-6">&nbsp;</div>
                        <div class="grid-9">
                            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator4" Display="Dynamic" ControlToValidate="txtZipCode" runat="server" Text="Zipcode is required" CssClass="error" ValidationGroup="addlocation"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                            <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegexZipCode" Display="Dynamic" ControlToValidate="txtZipCode" runat="server" CssClass="error" ValidationGroup="addlocation" Text="Invalid zip code" ValidationExpression="^\d{5}(?:[-\s]\d{4})?$"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
                        </div>
                        <div class="clear"></div>
                        <div class="grid-6">
                            <label for="<%=txtZipCode.ClientID%>">Zip Code <span class="required">*</span></label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="grid-9">
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtZipCode" runat="server" Width="300px" CssClass="too-short" MaxLength="5" onkeypress="return isNumberIntegerKey(event,this,13);"></asp:TextBox>
                        </div>

                        <div class="clear"></div>
                        <div class="grid-6">&nbsp;</div>
                        <div class="grid-9">
                            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvPhone" Display="Dynamic" ControlToValidate="txtPhone" runat="server" Text="Phone is required" CssClass="error" ValidationGroup="addlocation"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                            <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegexPhone" Display="Dynamic" ControlToValidate="txtPhone" runat="server" CssClass="error" Text="Invalid phone1" ValidationGroup="addlocation" ValidationExpression="((\(\d{3}\) ?)|(\d{3}-))?\d{3}-\d{4}"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
                        </div>
                        <div class="clear"></div>
                        <div class="grid-6">
                            <label for="<%=txtPhone.ClientID%>">Phone <span class="required">*</span></label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="grid-9">
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtPhone" runat="server" Width="300px" CssClass="too-short" onkeypress="mask(this, mphone);" MaxLength="15"></asp:TextBox>
                        </div>
                        <div class="clear"></div>
                        <div class="seperator-1"></div>
                        <div class="grid-6">&nbsp;</div>
                        <div class="grid-9">
                            <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator3" Display="Dynamic" ControlToValidate="txtEmail" runat="server" CssClass="error" Text="Invalid email" ValidationGroup="addlocation" ValidationExpression="^[\w-\.]+@([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]{2,4}$"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
                        </div>
                        <div class="clear"></div>
                        <div class="grid-6">
                            <label for="<%=txtEmail.ClientID%>">Email</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="grid-9">
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtEmail" runat="server" Width="300px" CssClass="too-long" ClientIDMode="Static" MaxLength="80"></asp:TextBox>
                        </div>
```

```
        <asp:Button ID="btnSaveNExit" runat="server" Text="Save & Exit" CausesValidation="true" Width="150px" Height="36px" CommandName="SAVENEXIT" />
        <asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" Text="Submit" CausesValidation="true" Width="150px" Height="36px" CommandName="SUBMIT" />
        <asp:Button ID="btnHome" runat="server" Text="Home" CausesValidation="false" Visible=" false" Width="150px" Height="36px" />
        <asp:Button ID="btnExit" runat="server" Text="Cancel" CausesValidation="false" Width="150px" Height="36px" CommandName="CANCEL" CssClass="cancel-rest-button" />
    </div>
</asp:Panel>
```

Comment: Do you have a question?

Comment: Yes how to validate that repeater when i click "Save" or "Submit" button